# can not access using root to fresh installed mysql in Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I need to access my mysql5.7 instance, using my mac terminal.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ facundo.laxalde$ brew install mysql@5.7

.
.
.

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.32: 319 files, 234.4MB

MacBook-Pro:~ facundo.laxalde$ brew services start mysql@5.7
==> Successfully started `mysql@5.7` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7)

MacBook-Pro:~ facundo.laxalde$ export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"

MacBook-Pro:~ facundo.laxalde$ mysqladmin -u root password 'yourpassword'
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

What is going on ?
this worked for me yesterday,

Comment: It's `--password` you forgot the `--` at the beginning.

Comment: Hi @Barmar 

MacBook-Pro:~ facundo.laxalde$ mysqladmin -u root --password 'yourpassword'
Enter password: 

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

same error

Comment: Apparently the documentation is wrong, you can't have a space between `--password` and the password, it has to be `--password='yourpassword'`